# Faye Websocket example bug?

Tags: ruby, websocket, faye, ruby-2.2

Over at [Faye Websocket for Ruby](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby), there is a specific example that is not working for me.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby/master/examples/app.rb

```
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'permessage_deflate'
require 'rack'

static  = Rack::File.new(File.dirname(__FILE__))
options = {:extensions => [PermessageDeflate], :ping => 5}

App = lambda do |env|
  if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)
    ws = Faye::WebSocket.new(env, ['irc', 'xmpp'], options)
    p [:open, ws.url, ws.version, ws.protocol]

    ws.onmessage = lambda do |event|
      ws.send(event.data)
    end

    ws.onclose = lambda do |event|
      p [:close, event.code, event.reason]
      ws = nil
    end

    ws.rack_response

  elsif Faye::EventSource.eventsource?(env)
    es   = Faye::EventSource.new(env)
    time = es.last_event_id.to_i

    p [:open, es.url, es.last_event_id]

    loop = EM.add_periodic_timer(2) do
      time += 1
      es.send("Time: #{time}")
      EM.add_timer(1) do
        es.send('Update!!', :event => 'update', :id => time) if es
      end
    end

    es.send("Welcome!\n\nThis is an EventSource server.")

    es.onclose = lambda do |event|
      EM.cancel_timer(loop)
      p [:close, es.url]
      es = nil
    end

    es.rack_response

  else
    static.call(env)
  end
end

def App.log(message)
end
```

The application does run, however the condition:

```
App = lambda do |env|
```

is not being met and is not iterating. Is this file supposed to be ran by an external source? Missing a file?

This is with running the file by command:

```
ruby app.rb
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here are a few thoughts: 1. `App = lambda ...` is not a condition, it's as assignment; 2. From the Faye website it seems that the example file is part of an example which consists of a number of files... You might be running only part of the example code...; 3. The example seems to be a Rack application, you might consider running it using `rackup` or using whatever server the example is expected to work with (probably `thin` or `puma`).

Comment: P.S. You might get more effective information by explaining what it is you are trying to do and what it is that you have tried so far to accomplish that goal.

Comment: You are correct, config.ru and app.rb are a single example together, has to be ran with one of the supported methods. For me, it detailed the command 'thin start -R examples/config.ru -p 7000', just had to change the directory and everything worked well. Thank you! I'l be posting an issue on their git about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The websocket server example I was trying is run by having both the 'app.rb' and 'config.ru' file. Thin, faye, permessage_deflate, json, and I think bundler have to be installed with 'gem install ' for this example to work.

The command to run the script is detailed in the 'config.ru', posting it here for reference

`thin start -R examples/config.ru -p 7000`